# VBA Run-Time Error when moving data and having 2 workbooks open

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on a VBA script that opens an XML file automatically, and parses data I need out of it.  The script opens a book2 window over top of book1 and runs until a point where it starts to grab data from column E and moves that data to a new sheet.  At that point I get an application Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error.

I noticed Excel is trying to grab data from book1 instead of book2.  Can anyone assist with helping me figure out where I am going wrong?  The issue arises after all the sheets are created in the script below. Thanks

```
Sub ModifyUpdate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wb2 As Workbook 
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String

ChDir Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\merged"

Set wb2 = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:= _
        Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\merged\merged_final.xml", _
        LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)


   ActiveSheet.Columns("L").Delete

    For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

        columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        Select Case columnHeading
            Case "name6", "port", "svc_name", "protocol", "port", "pluginID8", "plugin_name", "agent", "plugin_output"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else
                'Delete if the cell doesn't contain "112"
                If InStr(1, _
                   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value, _
                   "112", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then

                    ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

                End If
        End Select
    Next



Dim i As Long

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
'Deletes the entire row within the selection if the ENTIRE row contains no data.


'Work backwards because we are deleting rows.
For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
 Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i


    wb2.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "PPS"
    wb2.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "NIX_SW"
    wb2.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet4").Name = "WIN_SW"
    wb2.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet5").Name = "OS_Type"
    wb2.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet6").Select
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet6").Name = "WEB"

    wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    For Each Cell In wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E")

    If Cell.Value = "10107" Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow + 1).Select
        Selection.Copy

        wb2.Sheets("WEB").Select
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If lastRow > 1 Then lastRow = lastRow + 1
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lastRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is add workbook and worksheet references to all your ranges. You do this in most places but not everywhere, e.g. `Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow + 1).Select`. Then, get rid of all your Select statements and your code will get much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    Sub ModifyUpdate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String

    ChDir Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\merged"

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:= _
            Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\merged\merged_final.xml", _
            LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)

    ActiveSheet.Columns("L").Delete

    For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value
        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        Select Case columnHeading
            Case "name6", "port", "svc_name", "protocol", "port", "pluginID8", "plugin_name", "agent", "plugin_output"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else
                'Delete if the cell doesn't contain "112"
                If InStr(1, _
                   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value, _
                   "112", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
                End If
        End Select
    Next

    Dim i As Long

    'Deletes the entire row within the selection if the ENTIRE row contains no data.

    'Work backwards because we are deleting rows.
    For i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    wb2.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "PPS"
    wb2.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "NIX_SW"
    wb2.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "WIN_SW"
    wb2.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "OS_Type"
    wb2.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "WEB"

    For Each Cell In wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1", wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        If Cell.Value = "10107" Then
            matchRow = Cell.Row
            lastRow = wb2.Sheets("WEB").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow + 1).Copy wb2.Sheets("WEB").Range("A" & lastRow)
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    End Sub
```

Comment: On the Workbooks.Open line? Funny, that bit should be the same as in your original code, I didn't touch that line.

Comment: It was my error.   The xml file wasn't in the location it needed to be.  I am running the code now and will let you know what I come up with when complete.

Comment: The script is doing the same as before.  It creates the sheets and then gives me an Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error at the for loop.

Comment: I wonder if it's do with xml file which I hadn't noticed. Have just lost most of my internet access so difficult to check atm.

Comment: Try using just Sheets(1) in the For instead of the name.

Comment: I open excel and have a book1.  Run the script that opens the xml file, and it writes everything to book2.   If I open the xml file directly, and run the for loop it will work.  However, there is another part of the script that runs a powershell script to merge xml files together then I open the xml file.  So, I am trying to get it all done in one script.  The loop will run on the XML file if the xml file is opened directly.  I just can't figure out what is wrong with the loop when the XML file is opened in this manner.

Comment: Just saw your comment on Sheets(1).  I will try it next.

Comment: Does the For loop run at all? Also check the name of the sheet is Sheet1.

Comment: The Loop does run, and loops for a bit and then stops at Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow + 1).Select when I debug it.  Sheet1 is named as such.

Comment: What is the value of matchRow? You are not using my code if you are using that line because that's from your original code.

Comment: I have amended my code above as it will certainly error when it gets to the last row in the sheet. Assuming you are checking E1 downwards but amend if not.